# How to injection a generic interface with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, interface

I have the next error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type

The interface to inject:

```cs
public interface iContext<T> { }
```

how to use this interface?

```cs
public class UsersRepository : iUsersRepository
{
    readonly iContext<UserEntities> db;
    public UsersRepository(iContext<UserEntities> db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
}
```

How to add in startup:

```cs
//services.AddScoped(typeof(iContext<>), typeof(UserEntities));
services.AddScoped(typeof(iContext<>));
//services.AddTransient<iContext<UserEntities>>();
//services.AddSingleton<iContext<UserEntities>, UserEntities>();
```

Edited:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Infrastructure._01_DataAccess.iContext`1[T]' for service type 'Infrastructure._01_DataAccess.iContext`1[T]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 descriptors)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngineCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CompiledServiceProviderEngine..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngineCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Daviel.SPAIN-HOLIDAY\Source\Repos\dhmaker-user\WebApi\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: It is hard to reproduce the problem because you didn't present the full exception message, didn't add the full stack trace, and didn't show the `UserEntities` implementation. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Steven i edit with error

Comment: As a suggestion, the naming convention for interfaces, the 'i' needs to be in uppercase. The 'iUsersRepository' turns 'IUsersRepository'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a concrete class that implements `iContext<T>`, like this:

`services.AddScoped(typeof(iContext<>), typeof(Context<>));`

where `Context<T>` is a class that implements `iContext<T>`.

Comment: Hi. i try this but i receive the same error

Comment: Are you able to resolve `UserEntities` and any/all other dependencies of the `IContext<T>` impelementation?